# Importing more than 255 columns data from SQL to excel using SSIS package

Tags: excel, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, data-import

A few day back, I had a requirement from the client to import/dump the data from SQL server (which was a result set of multiple joins producing more than 300 columns) into excel on daily basis. However, while running the utility, It gave Too many Field error.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I used Flat File Destination Task to load all the required data (more than 300 columns) to csv file. And later saved this csv as excel.

This is the only workaround I achieved for the above scenario.